# Batch Generate PDFs with dynamic content

Tags: windows-7, pdf, mailing-list, templating

OK. This should be an easy one.

**Requirements:**

- Windows 7 compatible
- Can somehow get a list of e-mails from Outlook

**Problem**

- Given a list of e-mail addresses of a group of customers, I need to be able to dynamically generate and replace text in a PDF, and render a new PDF customized for each person.

Comment: Will the dynamic data be within body text, requiring reflows?

Comment: It is in the body text. Mainly a name and a registration number.